# Semantic zoom in D3.js for Force-Directed Layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a problem regarding "semantic zooming".

Basically, i want to use the concept of this d3.js example with the nodes + arrows. I already made some custom specification, but they have nothing to do with my problem. Here the original one:
    http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292

I wanted to compare it with the "SVG semantic zooming" feature of
   http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680957
because my dataset gets pretty crowdy over the time and this feature would be awesome. I tried several things, but i always get stuck with the "translate" problem. I have the SVG elements in the original version with `transfrom = "translate(100,200) //any number of coordinate possible here`

Especially i cannot change them in combination with the arrows. :/

I prepared a jsfiddle for you here:
  http://jsfiddle.net/z4pr90qs/
`.`

I'd appreciate really if you could help me out!

Best, Andrea

Comment: What question are you asking here?

Comment: You're working on force.layout. Here's an sample Force + Drag + Zoom: JSFiddlehttp://jsfiddle.net/blt909/aVhd8/20/. Hope this help

Comment: @RobertLongson, it was about the combination of this force layout + zooming.

Comment: @Klaujesi Many many thanks to you! This problem killed a lot of my time. You solved it perfectly. Even with dragging in addition :)